# Misfiring problems

Tags: chevrolet, misfire, silverado

I have 98 Sliverodo 5.7 vortex. It ran hot on me and I was told it was my head. Well turns out that it was an intake gasket. So I replaced the head and intake gaskets. Once I put it all back together I had a misfire on cylinder #5. Was told it could be my spyder injectors. So I cahaned the injector out, now I have a misfire on cylinder #4.... replaced the injector again and now the misfire is back at cylinder #5. New wires and plugs, new distributor, coil pack and all..

Does ANYONE have any information on this that can help with my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Is it a dead miss, meaning all the time, cold, hot, idle, and under a load?

Comment: Just about all the time.

Comment: I can reset the code and it will run ok but when I stop for a light or stop sign the check engine light will come on

Comment: Spider injectors have a specific location when installing each injector, did you get this right?

Comment: Yes both times I made sure of it